# Laravel 5 - Resource Controller in Subfolder

Tags: restful-architecture, laravel-5

Take a look at this folder structure:

```
Controllers
  -> User
    - UserController.php
```

And this is what i got in my `routes.php`:

```
Route::resource('user', 'User\UserController');
```

What am I doing wrong? I got a 404 error.

Comment: Check the class name at controller file. Also, is this problem shown with other controller? Finally, please check the controller namespace.

Comment: @manix This was it. I just had to change the namespace. After that my Routes worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have your controllers nested try to use underscores instead of backslashes, try this

```
Route::resource('user', 'User_UserController');
```